# QtCreator incorrect marks Qml syntax

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator

I use QtCreator 5.0.2 with Qt 5.15.2. I created simple QML program

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
}
```

But QtCreator marks "title" property like incorrect. And Creator also highlighted other properties like "x", "y" etc. The application runs good. Why this happened? How to fix it?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This issue was fixed in QtCreator 11.0.2
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-28468